# Forward function and variables into sudo su - <user> <<EOF

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables, ksh, function

I have declared functions and variables in bash/ksh and I need to forward them into `sudo su - {user} << EOF`:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_f() {
echo "LOG line: $@"
}

extVAR="yourName"

sudo su - <user> << EOF
  intVAR=$(date)
  log_f ${intVAR} ${extVAR}
EOF
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo su -`, which is a complicated way of writing `sudo -i`, constructs a pristine environment. That's the point of a login shell. Even a plain `sudo` removes most variables from the environment. Furthermore `sudo` is an external command; there's no way to elevate privileges in the shell script itself, only to run an external program (`sudo`) with extra privileges, and that means any shell variables (i.e. non-exported variables) and functions defined in the parent shell won't be available in the child shell.

You can pass environment variables through by not invoking a login shell (`sudo bash` instead of `sudo su -` or `sudo -i`) and configuring sudo to let these variables through (with `Defaults !env_reset` or `Defaults env_keep=…` in the `sudoers` file). This won't help you for functions (although bash has a function export facility, sudo blocks it).

The normal way to get your functions in the child shell would be to define them there. Take care of quoting: if you use `<<EOF` for the here document, the content of the here document is first expanded by the parent shell, and the result of that expansion becomes the script that the child shell sees. That is, if you write

```
sudo -u "$target_user" -i <<EOF
echo "$(whoami)"
EOF
```

this displays the name of the original user, not the target user. To avoid this first phase of expansion, quote the here document marker after the `<<` operator:

```
sudo -u "$target_user" -i <<'EOF'
echo "$(whoami)"
EOF
```

So if you don't need to pass data from the parent shell to the child shell, you can use a quoted here document:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u "$target_user" -i  <<'EOF'
log_f() {
echo "LOG line: $@"
}
intVAR=$(date)
log_f "${intVAR}"
EOF
```

While you can make use of an unquoted here document marker to pass data from the parent shell to the child shell, this only works if the data doesn't contain any special character. That's because in a script like

```
sudo -u "$target_user" -i <<EOF
echo "$(whoami)"
EOF
```

the output of `whoami` becomes a bit of shell code, not a string. For example, if the `whoami` command returned `"; rm -rf /; "true` then the child shell would execute the command `echo ""; rm -rf /; "true"`.

If you need to pass data from the parent shell, a simple way is to pass it as arguments. Invoke the child shell explicitly and pass it positional parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash
extVAR="yourName"
sudo -u "$target_user" -i sh  _ "$extVAR" <<'EOF'
  log_f() {
  echo "LOG line: $@"
  }
  intVAR=$(date)
  log_f "${intVAR}" "${1}"
EOF
```

If you have multiple variables to pass, it will be more readable to pass them by name. Call `env` explicitly to set environment variables for the child shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
extVAR="yourName"
sudo -u "$target_user" -i env extVAR="$extVAR" sh <<'EOF'
  log_f() {
  echo "LOG line: $@"
  }
  intVAR=$(date)
  log_f "${intVAR}" "${1}"
EOF
```

Note that if you expected `/etc/profile` and the target user's `~/.profile` to be read, you'll have to read them explicitly, or call `bash --login` instead of `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because the function `log_f` is not declared in the `sudo su -` shell you launch. Instead:

```
extVAR="yourName"

sudo su - <user> << EOF

log_f() {
echo "LOG line: $@"
}

  intVAR=$(date)
  log_f ${intVAR} ${extVAR}
EOF
```

You need to get the function defined in the root subshell. That might do it, but.... I don't know what most of that stuff does. At least - so long as neither `sudo` nor `su` needs stdin to read a password - that should get `log_f()` declared.

I trust that you mean to expand those values into the root shell's input, by the way. If you do not mean to do so then you should quote `EOF` and the vars themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to pass an array in and had some trouble, but had success after a while by echoing the array's values to an `env`-key and wrapping the intended code in `bash -c '<intended code>'`, and basically have it recreating the array, eg.:`INNER_KEY=($<env_key>)`.

For examlpe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PLUGINS=(foo bar baz)
sudo -u <some-user> -i env PLUGINS="`echo ${PLUGINS[@]}`" sh <<'EOF'
  bash -c '
    FOO=($PLUGINS);
    echo values: \[${FOO[@]}\];

    for pl in ${FOO[@]};
      do echo value: $pl;
    done;
  '
EOF
```

The problem was that I could not directly do something like the following (not using `bash -c '...'`):

```
FOO=($PLUGINS);
for pl in ${FOO[@]};
...
```